# Discord PYthon bot deleting own message after some time

Tags: python, discord, bots

my bot has a Clear command. But if you clear, the bot will send a message that says, that you cleared this chat... So how can i delete it after like 10 Seconds using maby asyncio...
Heres my Code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', description="This is a bot")

@bot.command(aliases=['c'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount: int = None):
    if amount == 0:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=10000000000000000000000)
        await ctx.send("Cleared the entire chat!")
        print("Cleared the chat!")
    else:
        if amount >= 1:
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
            await ctx.send("Done!")
            print(f"Cleared {amount} messages!")
```

Thanks for helping...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
await ctx.send("...", delete_after=10.0)
```

The parameter `delete_after` will delete the message after 10s.

Alternatively, you can also assign the message to a variable, wait, and then delete.

```py
msg = await ctx.send("...")
await asyncio.sleep(10.0)
await msg.delete()
```